# Longtable vertical placement

Tags: vertical-alignment, longtable

I'm fighting with Google. I have a `longtable` with manual breaks, so in every page there is an empty space after the table, I want to vertically center the `longtable`. How can I do that?

Comment: you'll never win a battle with google -- they've got the nsa on their side...

Comment: good question, answer wasn't totally obvious even if I have seen longtable before:-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

It is possible that the longtable documentation doesn't mention this, but you can use:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}



{
\makeatletter
\def\@textbottom{\vskip0pt plus 1fill}
\let\@texttop\@textbottom
\makeatother

\begin{longtable}{cc}
HHH&HHH
\endhead
FFF&FFF
\endfoot
a111&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\
\pagebreak
a222&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\
\pagebreak
a333&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\
\pagebreak
a444&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\
\end{longtable}
\clearpage
}

normal text

\end{document}
```

Comment: That solved the problem